# Xamarin Forms || Streaming Camera feed to Web API

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am working on a Image recognition project where I want to recognize a person using Xamarin.Forms Mobile App (Android and iOS).

I am able to create custom camera for both platforms and Also I have Web Api using python which receives stream / video / Image file and provides the output.

I want to either click photo automatically when Person is detected in the camera and send this image to server or If possible can send live stream from camera to API but I am not able to find any way to either detect and auto capture image or stream the camera output to WebApi.

Any Sample will help

Note: I don't want to use Cognitive Services or any paid server.

Comment: What is your actual question?  Do you want to know how to stream the video to a server?  Or are you asking how to implement facial recognition?

Comment: How to stream the video to a server using Xamarin.Forms

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=xamarin+stream+video+to+server+site:stackoverflow.com